# C++, Visual Studio 2015, Vector iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++

Ok, so i managed to write a method for deleting missles in my game, but i am constantly getting this error and i don't know why. Any ideas how to deal with the problem? Besides, i'd like to get rid of this i iterator, but then i don't know how to use properly delete and erase for the missle.

```
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = missle_vector.begin(); it != missle_vector.end(); ++it) {
            score += missle_vector[i]->collision(i, missle_vector, enemy_vector, obstacle_vector, 1);
            displayMissle(**it);
            (*it)->moove(50, 0);
            i++;
        }
    } //this is how i use it

int Missle::collision(unsigned int i, vector <Missle*> &missle_vector, vector <Enemy*> &enemy_vector,
                            vector <Obstacle*> &obstacle_vector, bool G)
{
int hit=0;
for (auto it=enemy_vector.begin(); it!=enemy_vector.end(); )
{
    double x, y;
    x=(*it)->getX()-getX();
    y=(*it)->getY()-getY();
    if (x<64 && x>-151 && y<14 && y>-103)
    {
        delete  missle_vector[i];
        missle_vector.erase(missle_vector.begin() + i);
        delete *it;
        enemy_vector.erase(it);
        hit++;
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
if(G){
for (auto it=obstacle_vector.begin(); it!=obstacle_vector.end(); ++it)
    {
        double x, y;
        x=(*it)->getX()-getX();
        y=(*it)->getY()-getY();
        if (x<64 && x>-61 && y<14 && y>-61)
        {
            delete  missle_vector[i];
            missle_vector.erase(missle_vector.begin()+i);
        }
    }
}
if (getX()>1920)
{
    delete missle_vector[i];
    missle_vector.erase(missle_vector.begin()+i);
}
return hit;
} //method itself
```

Comment: It's rather unclear on what this code is supposed to actually *do*. For example, I see you deleting "`missle_vector[i]` [sic]" in a loop. But `i` doesn't change. Is that intentional? I know that the subsequent call to `erase` removes that element from the vector, but it's not clear to me *why* you want to remove the `i`-th index from that vector. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have edited the way i put the method to use. This should clear the misunderstanding.

Comment: First, that doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. Second, that only shows *more problems and bugs*, since you're trying to use an iterator that may have been invalidated. Basically, the logic of all of these systems needs to be re-thought from square one.

Answer (score 1):

This is an assertion:

```
Vector iterator not dereferencable
```

and it means you are derefencing and iterator which for example is end iterator. For example this short example will generate this assertion:

```
std::vector<int> v;
*v.end();
```

this assertion should appear at runtime during debugging and will allow you to find exact place where problem exissts. In Visual Studio you can use debugger to lookup local variables, call stack.

[edit]

one place where you can get this assertion in your code is here:

```
 enemy_vector.erase(it);
```

this should be:

```
 it = enemy_vector.erase(it);
```

otherwise in next iteration your it will be invalid and *it will result in `Vector iterator not dereferencable`. Even `it!=enemy_vector.end()` should be Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I completely forgot about this. But this was not the only case. Even if i leave only the last if (last 5 lines) in the method, i get this error.

Comment: When you get the error running under a debugger, the stack trace should  give you information about the invalid iterator's use.  That may also give you a clue as to why the iterator is invalid.

Comment: For example, in the loop where you call `missle_vector.erase(missle_vector.begin()+i);`, the `it ` iterator used for loop control may be invalidated depending on how it relates to the `i` index.